# Google Drive on Login

Tags: 14.04, mount, google-drive

I am fairly new to the Linux world, and i was wondering how could i mount my google drive using `google-drive-ocamlfuse` only when i login with my personal account.

From what i understand i can not use `fstab`, since it contains system-wide file system definition and i do not want everyone using my computer to have access to my personal google-drive.

I am looking for something similar for network shares and other mounts which are to be used only by the the specific logged on user?

Thanks,

Comment: Also see https://linuxconfig.org/google-drive-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Answer (score 1):

You can add the command to mount Google Drive with google-drive-ocamlfuse to your startup applications. To do this, launch Startup Applications from your applications menu, add a new startup entry, and use the following as the command:

```
sh -c "google-drive-ocamlfuse mountpoint"
```

Where "mountpoint" is the mount point for Google Drive. For example, if you've created a folder called "GoogleDrive" in your home folder, use this as the startup command:

```
sh -c "google-drive-ocamlfuse ~/GoogleDrive"
```